# Change the value of min-h-full or add class to set min-height with Tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind, I'm trying to change the default value of the min-h-full class. Actually set to 100% , I want to change this for a calc.

Explain, I want this :

`calc(100vh - (headerHeight + footerHeight)`

so I have this

`calc(100vh - 296px)`

What I've tested :

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            minHeight: {
                'full': '100px',
            }
        },
        fontFamily: {
            title: ['Righteous', 'sans-serif'],
            body: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

This code doesn't work , the min-h-height stuck to 100%

and I've tried this :

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        minHeight: {
            'full': '100px',
        },
        fontFamily: {
            title: ['Righteous', 'sans-serif'],
            body: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

This code doesn't work too.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are differences between two code snippets

Comment: @Mr.roland oh thank I update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `full` without quote

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        minHeight: {
            full: '100px',
        },
        fontFamily: {
            title: ['Righteous', 'sans-serif'],
            body: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],
        },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```